# equivalent of an <iframe> using content in the same document

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a number of html documents in a structure that are quite long. The visual scrolling look isn't very nice so I'd like to put the content into the equivalent of an iframe that is much more visually appealing.

I don't really want to have to add another document for each document I want to turn into an iframe however. so rather than saying

```
<html>
  <body>
   <iframe src="mydocument.html">
   </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like the same effect (scroll bar, fixed border, scrolling inner text) with content that looks like

```
<html>
  <body>
   <iframe>
     a great lot of content
     that is already on a set
     of html pages.
   </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course it doesn't have to be an iframe if another tag or some css wizardry will accomplish the same thing. It is just one section of each page (the `#main` content) that goes into the frame. I have other navigation type things that I'd like to leave untouched.

Any thoughts very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at implementing an accordion?

Comment: Hi @TomRudge I'm not familiar with that. What is that, and how would I implement it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m_raffaele/FkzLj/ to simplify it for you, just html and css make this one work

Comment: Thats pretty incredible @TomRudge. Thanks for showing it to me. I think perhaps for my next project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm getting this correctly, it should be enough just to add this to your parent container:

```
#content{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 500px;
}
```

The container will have a fixed height, and if the content inside is larger than that defined size, you'll get a scrollbar to allow for content scrolling;

Comment: Just for my curiosity, in iframe, you can put the URL, but in this case, where will you make that come? The point of the OP is making iframe equivalent i.e characteristics and not just a div with id.

Comment: If I understood correctly, all of the content is on one page, and he just wants to limit the size of that content to a certain area

Comment: This is perfect thank you @SlavenkoMiljic. NathanLee, I phrased my question badly, I can apply the rest of the css features into the `id` directly